# not able to view pdf files in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: macos, pdf, intellij-idea, adobe, intellij-15

PDF files are not opening in IntelliJ 15.Although i got the associated file 
application set up in the Mac OSX. The files are not getting viewed.

I tried to change the application associated from Mac's default "preview"
to Adobe reader but still Intellij cannot view the file when i double click on it.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to open the .pdf s IN IntelliJ or are your trying to open the .pdf in a .pdf Reader FROM IntelliJ?

Comment: sorry could not understand your question completely.I am opening the pdf file(.pdf) in intellij. Where the OS filetype is associated with Adobe Reader ,preview. both does not work.

Comment: Okay I'll refrase: When you double click on the pdf file in IntelliJ, do you want to see the PDF appear in IntelliJ or do you want Adobe Reader to open and display the PDF?

Comment: adobe reader to open from intellij.

Comment: Then this has nothing to do with programming or intellij. Simply [configure your Operating System to open .pdf files with Adobe Reader.](http://www.imore.com/how-change-default-apps-os-x)

Comment: @Harmelodic I think the OP wants to open pdf file inside Intellij, indeed it's not about programming, but it's a way of viewing PDF file without quitting the IDE, which is useful sometimes.

Comment: There is a plugin which allows you to view pdfs inside Intellij.